# Apache SSI redhat 6

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

I'm trying to figure out how the apache SSI module works,

Following [mod_include pache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html) here is my configuration:

```
LoadModule include_module       /logiciel/httpd/httpd/modules/mod_include.so
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
<Directory test>
 # 
 Options Includes
 </Directory>
```

And of course it is not working.

What I'm doing wrong ? it seems like I did the same as this : [another SSI post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200522/apache-not-processing-basic-ssi), my test.shtml file contains:

```
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
```

Using apache 2.4 on rhel6,

Edit virtual configuration:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "logs/error_log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="#-1" id=4294967295 not_used
Group: name="#-1" id=4294967295 not_used
```

edit : second command:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 12 2012 11:40:57
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:6
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-UTIL 1.5.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-UTIL 1.5.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/httpd/Apache_2.4.3"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/httpd/Apache_2.4.3/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

And thanks again.

Comment: It would be good to include any relevant error messages usually found in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I have no relevant error messages except something about No JkLOgFile defined but I think it's not related ?

Comment: Looks like the modules loaded fine... now let's look at other configuration items so we know where to start... `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS -D DUMP_RUN_CFG`  and `httpd -V`

Comment: @RubberStamp done

Comment: From the vhosts output it looks like you are running SELinux.  Is that correct?

Comment: Nope it's not running

Comment: Something is missing from your system configuration listed here... the user id for apache is not a valid id number. Perhaps selinux is still running... `sestatus`  ?

Comment: Selinux is disabled, i wonder if it's not another module who interferes with mod include, is that possible ?

Comment: The problem you are having seems unlikely to be related directly to the `include` module.  It seems likely to be a result of some non-standard system configuration... probably some security issues either a non-standard chroot or some policy somewhere...  I can't duplicate your non-working `SSI` configuration.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your efforts RubberStamp, I'm going to dig into this until I find a solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `include` module is loading correctly, and you've loaded the `mime` module which is a dependency of `include`...

You probably need to have the complete directory listed, like this:

```
/var/www/html/test
```

rather than simply `test` and I usually find that `+Includes` is a good idea rather than `Includes`. So, the working configuration should look something like this:

```
LoadModule include_module    /logiciel/httpd/httpd/modules/mod_include.so
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
<Directory /var/www/html/test>
 # 
Options +Includes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Not working, and no error related to loading mod_include, for the directory a lot of html pages are reachable and using ServerRoot and DocumentRoot var

Comment: @gatemed: It works on my system.  You must have something else configured... please add the output of `apachectl -M` to your question... or the equivalent in RHEL6... `service httpd -M`